# c# - obtain the filename of base64 encoded file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encoding, base64

Im trying to obtain the name of a infopath 2007 attachment file (inside an xml, which is encoded by default in base64Binary), i have achieved this before with the same code but for some reason i cant obtain the original file name, of the  attachments inside xml files im using now (which i need to find the attachment's .extension and the file also needs to have the same name as before), however if i write the file extension manually i can export the file, so my question is: why can i write the file from the base64 string successfully and im not able to get its name.
**Notes:**

- im currently trying to decode images, im not sure if the problems might be here, however as mentioned if i know the .ext and type it manually i can decode it
- the xml file from where im getting the attachment encoded string was 'exported'(for lack of a better word, saved?) from infopath 2007
- the `decodeFromBase64` works fine
- `getFileName` worked on diffrent 'pack' of xml i used before, as far as i know there arent any relevant diffrences because im able to obtain the encoded string and decode the file
- im using code extremely simillar to that provided in the decoding class, by microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/892730/how-to-encode-and-decode-a-file-attachment-programmatically-by-using-visual-c-in-infopath-2003

code to write the file (that works):

```
public static void decodeFromBase64(string encodedString)
{
    using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Create("D:\\some dir\\file.png"))
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(file);
        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
}
```

code to get the file name, that throws: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' **here:**
 /**********************************************/

```
byte[] _fileNameBytes = _theReader.ReadBytes(_attachmentNameLength);
```

/**********************************************/

```
  public static string getFileName(string attachedFile)
    {
        string fname;
        byte[] thdata = Convert.FromBase64String(attachedFile);

            Encoding _encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            using (MemoryStream _memoryStream = new MemoryStream(thdata))
            {

                BinaryReader _theReader = new BinaryReader(_memoryStream);
                _theReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                byte[] _headerData = _theReader.ReadBytes(16);

                int _fileSize = (int)_theReader.ReadUInt32();
                int _attachmentNameLength = (int)_theReader.ReadUInt32() * 2;

                byte[] _fileNameBytes = _theReader.ReadBytes(_attachmentNameLength);
                fname = _encoding.GetString(_fileNameBytes, 0, _attachmentNameLength - 2);
                if (fname.Length > 0)
                    return fname;
            }
        return fname;
    }
```

**edit:**

- i forgot to mention that using the same code awhile ago i tried to decode a string encoded from the previous files and it worked

**edit2:**
**############################## SOLVED #################################**
Even though i found the solution im not sure of the **exact** source of the problem. The integrety of my encoded string was somehow corrupted (somehow i messed up the construction of my test templates, after testing the xml files where the attachments were, everything went great **ALSO** the only files whose encoded strings didnt work so far were my own, which makes total sense considering i never used infopath directly before)
**For future reference**: here are official decoder and encoder classes

- InfoPath 2003
  support.microsoft _com/en-us/help/892730/how-to-encode-and-decode-a-file-attachment-programmatically-by-using-visual-c-in-infopath-2003
- InfoPath 2007 and 2010
  support.microsoft _com/en-us/help/2517906/how-to-encode-and-to-decode-a-file-attachment-programmatically-by-using-visual-c-in-infopath-2010-or-in-infopath-2007
  ***(cant post more than 2 links, i'll edit it later)***

Comment: Looks to me like the numeric value in _attachmentNameLength is bigger than the bytes remaining in the stream, which would cause your ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Take a look in debug at that value, the size of the stream, and the stream's position at that point. If I'm right something is off in your calculation of the name size and you are ending up with a much higher value than you think.

Comment: @Kevin you are right, thats the case, but im trying with some other encoded files and everything works fine and i cant really understand how i can get the name of only some files when i can decode all of them (which implies that the file probably wasnt wrongfuly encoded)